# free-form select of picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am working on a windows application in C# where I want to select any region of a picturebox control like we can do in ms paint using tool "Free-Form Select"   and latter I can edit this region as well. 
I am drawing a region using code below:

```
private void picturemap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

        {
              if (StartDrawing)
              {
                    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                    {
                          paintCurrentPosition(3, Color.Red, e.X, e.Y);
                    }
              }
        }
        private void paintCurrentPosition(int thickness, Color colorPen, int x, int y)
        {
              SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colorPen);
              bmp = new Bitmap(picturemap.Image);
              gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
              gr.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, thickness, thickness);

              picturemap.Image = bmp;
        }
```

Now I want to select the region what i drawn here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about Bitmap.Clone(), where your region is passed in as a Rectangle? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx

Comment: I think this question is way to broad - as it seems to me you want to select the red box - you drew. Put in order to do this you have to save the info of the boxes you inserted somewhere (not in the bitmap you are drawing). Only then you can select them - so the design of your app will get way more complicated and I don't think we can give you a short answer here...

Comment: i am drawing the red boxes just to mark a custom region not a rectangular one, if there is another way to select a region please give me example

Comment: Hi  Jason,
Bitmap.Clone() method takes a rectangle but my requirement is to select a custom area as free-form select in ms paint.

Comment: Did you try making use of [Graphics.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store each coordinate of your free form shape into a GrphicsPath object while the user is drawing. On mouse up, be sure to close the path.

Later when the user is hovering their mouse over the picture box with no mouse buttons pressed, perform a HitTest(e.X, e.Y) on mouse move to determine if the current coordinates  lie within the graphics path region.

There are many simple algorithms out there which can perform a HitTest for you extremely fast without causing computation lag.

This would be similar to doing a rectangle.Contains(x, y) test.